# Get reference to vue-router router-link component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a component with

```
<router-link to="page"></router-link>
<router-view></router-view>
```

In the Page component where the link links to, I fire an event. The component holding the link needs a subscription to that event. How do I get a reference to the Page component and subscribe to its events? As I have not explicitly declared `<page></page>` in the component holding the `<router-link>` and `router-view`, I can't use the normal `@event` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the [`$root`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-root) to [`$emit`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit) an event on and listen [`$on`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit) too.

Simple use anywhere in your application;

```js
this.$root.$emit('myCustomEvent', 'hello world')

/* somewhere else in your app */
this.$root.$on('myCustomEvent', (msg) => {
  /* handle the custom event */
  console.log(msg)
})
```

---

Full example

```html
<!-- src/App.vue -->
<template lang="html">
  <div>
    <router-link to="page">Go to Page</router-link>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'app',
    mounted () {
      this.$root.$on('pageEvent', this.handlePageEvent)
    },
    beforeDestroy () {
      // make sure you cleanup the event
      this.$root.$off('pageEvent', this.handlePageEvent)
    },
    methods: {
      handlePageEvent (ev) {
        console.log('you clicked me from within')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

```html
<!-- src/Page.vue -->
<template>
  <div>
    <a @click="$root.$emit('pageEvent')">Click Me</a>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Add 'this.' before handlePageEvent
this.$root.$on('pageEvent', this.handlePageEvent)